# Unable to execute add functionality Struts2-jquery-grid to add new data

Tags: jqgrid, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

I am working using Struts2-jquery-grid and I am able to edit / delete the existing entry. But I am facing problem to add new entry. I tried to figure out why the add functionality is not working. All of my codes are like the following:

gridTable.jsp

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsonFormatDate" />
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond" />
<sjg:grid id="gridtable"
        dataType="json"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="gridModel"

        editurl="gridTableEdit"

        navigator="true"
        navigatorAdd="true"
        navigatorEdit="true"        
        navigatorDelete="true"
>

<sjg:gridColumn name="bookID" index="bookID" title="bookID" sortable="true" editable="true" hidden="false" key="true"/>
<sjg:gridColumn name="bookTitle" index="bookTitle" title="bookTitle" editable="true" />
</sjg:grid>
```

Action layer [ridTable.java]:

```
public class GridTable extends ActionSupport {

    int id;
    String oper;
    String bookTitle;

    //getter and setter

    // display the grid into the jsp page
    public String gridTableDisplay() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String gridTableEdit() {

        if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
            BookBusiness business = new Business();
            business.addBook(bookTitle);
        }

        else if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {
            BookBusiness business = new Business();
            business.editBook(bookTitle);
        }

        else if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase("del")) {
            BookBusiness business = new Business();
            business.deleteBook(bookTitle);
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Business layer [BookBusiness.java]

```
public void addBook(String bookTitle) {
        BookDAO dao = new BookDAO();
        Book newBook = new Book();
        newBook.setTitle(bookTitle)
        dao.updateBook(newBook);
}

public Book editBook(....) {
...
}

public void deleteBook(...) {
....
}
```

DAO layer [BookDAO.java]

```
.....
```

I tried to execute the add functionality but failed. Can you tell me what exactly causing the problem? I executed the code from the business class and I find that the code is working finely and it is able to add new entry. But it fails to add form grid.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you named the first column `bookId`, the grid will use `id` for the column that has `key=true`. When you use the grid to perform an add, `setId()` will be called with a value of null. You cannot set a null to a primitive type, so you need to change your `int id;` property and associated getter/setter to use `Integer` instead of `int`. This should resolve your issue.